# Extract a word in a dynamic string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, substring

In this example, I want to extract the given price in the string.

```js
const string = 'I am a long sentence! My price is $5,000 on a discount!';
const price = string.substring(string.lastIndexOf("$")+1,string.lastIndexOf(" "));
document.write(price);
```

The above method won't work because it selects the last index of a space (`" "`)

How do I go about getting the space right after the price ?

---

**EDIT**:

The string might be anything else! I have no control over it, I just want to extract the price. In case I didn't make that clear.

Comment: Look for space followed by 'on' instead.

Comment: I can't do that because the sentence won't always contain the 'on' word after the price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions aren't always the right tool, but for this case it seems like an obvious choice. What you really want is everything that matches a `$` followed by a mixture of numbers and commas, ending at any other character.

```js
const re = /\$[\d,]+/
const string = 'I am a long sentence! My price is $5,000 on a discount!';
const prices = re.exec(string);
console.log(prices[0]);
```

You might want to expand the pattern, for example, to also match `.` -- `/\$[\d,.]+` (would capture "$5,000.25") or to be extra permissive, just anything but a space: `/\$[^ ]+/` (would capture "$tonsofmoney").

Comment: I accepted your answer since even though I haven't mentioned specifically. The dynamic sentence might contain a period `.` after the price. I have to get my hands dirty and study some regular expressions I guess!

Answer (score 2):

```
const string = 'I am a long sentence! My price is $5,000 on a discount!';
    const price =string.split('$')[1]//text after $
             .split(' ')[0];// text after $ and before space
    document.write(price);
```

```js
const string = 'I am a long sentence! My price is $5,000 on a discount!';
const price =string.split('$')[1].split(' ')[0];
document.write(price);
```

or

```js
const string = 'I am a long sentence! My price is $5,000 on a discount!';
    const price =string.match(/\$[0-9]*,[0-9]*/);
//match $XXX,XXX in the string and estract it
    document.write(price);
```

Comment: Can you please briefly explain how the above code works? Thank you  EDIT: The second method won't work! As I mentioned, the string given to me is a dynamic, means that won't be the same every time.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
const string = 'I am a long sentence! My price is $5,000 on a   discount!';
const price = (string.split("$")[1].split(" ")[0]);
document.write(price);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. I'm splitting it into multiple rows for better readability.

```js
const string = 'I am a long sentence! My price is $5,000 on a discount!';
var dollarPosition = string.lastIndexOf("$");
var nextSpace = string.indexOf(" ", dollarPosition+1);
const price = string.substring(dollarPosition+1,nextSpace);
document.write(price);
```

Comment: This way works perfectly for this case, thanks for breaking it into steps, seems clear now !

Answer (score 1):

```js
const string = 'I am a long sentence! My price is $5,000 on a discount!' +
  'Another price: $120.';

var m = string.match(/\$[\d,]+/g);
var i, price;
if (m) {
  for (i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
    price = m[i].replace('$', '');
    console.log(price);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`string.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```js
const string = 'I am a long sentence! My price is $5,000 on a discount!';
const price = (string.split('$')[1]).split(' ')[0];
document.write(price);
```

this splits the string at the first index of $ and takes the part after the $.
than it splits the string at the first appearance of a space and takes the part before the space.

note that this expects that there is only 1 $ sign in the string.